# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

My Bluetooth is not working in my ubuntu 18.04(I recently installed it). I have tried almost all answers on StackExchange, but no use.

Here are some commands that might help you understand the problem.

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
lines 1-4/4 (END)
```

I know it can be started by
`systemctl start bluetooth` but it is of no use, as it does not change any thing except the status.

And

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
```

It does not do any thing except a blank cursor which I have to cancel manually.

I also have installed bluez as someone said in any answer. Version is

```
$ dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1
```

If I start bluetooth service by `$ systemctl start bluetooth` then `bluetoothctl` shows following.

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# power
Missing on/off argument
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

But I can see a small bluetooth ugly symbol at top(Maybe because of bluez), but turing it on pops up a window as following
[image]

Please help me solve this problem.

#### Edit

Also 1 more command might help you, after starting bluetooth, I typed this too

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ce
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:1055 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: does your device appear when you execute `hciconfig` ?

Comment: No. But it was working in my Windows 10.

Comment: well, but one this doesnt mean the other. you might need some drivers.

Comment: How to get those. Can you give me some link. I am not good with linux

Answer (score 0):

i installed BLUEMAN :

```
sudo apt-get install blueman -y && blueman-manager
```

and it worked for me

NB : prior to this you might need to install the following :

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill -y

sudo rfkill list

sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth

sudo service bluetooth start
```